# random number generator and seed

Tags: random, openssl

I'm working with openssl cryptographic libraries, I'm new to all these cryptographic stuffs and slowly I'm learning all these. I have a doubt regarding random number generator, I'm using `RAND_pseudo_bytes()` for generating a pseudo random number. I'm providing a seed to it with my required entropy. But my doubt is if we provide same seed twice, will the random number generator generate the same random number ?

Comment: You will probably find the people who know the answer to this question over at [crypto.stackexchange.com](http://crypto.stackexchange.com)

Comment: If the seed is same, then it should generate the same sequence.

Comment: @Joe: This question isn't really a very good fit for crypto.SE, although admittedly the way it's asked here makes it a bit hard to tell: "How do cryptographic PRNGs work?" would be a good question for crypto.SE (except maybe a bit too broad); "How does the OpenSSL PRNG work?" would be marginally on topic, while "How do I use the OpenSSL PRNG?" would be off topic for crypto. This question as asked here looks sort of like the second type, but [the real question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9983) behind it is closer to the last one.

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo random number generators are deterministic. They should however be constructed in such a way that it is hard to generate cycles (if it ever gets to a previous state, it will generate identical randoms, until it gets into the next loop, without end).

If you start off a pseudo random number generator with the same seed than it *will* generate the same output. This was an issue in Ubuntu where the response to a static code analysis led to the removal of any randoms during seeding.

Note that most pseudo random number generators *mix in* additional seed/entropy in the current state. So once a pseudo random number generator is well seeded, it will keep on producing random numbers. Many libraries do seed the random number generator by a good entropy source (e.g. `/dev/random` or the pre-seeded `/dev/urandom` on linux systems) by default.

Of course, it does not hurt to test.